directoryName option not working for AzureDataLake Camel consumer
I'm trying to setup a camel route in java, reading a csv in an Azure Data Lake and processing it. So far, it looks like this :
from("direct:updateValues")
        .pollEnrich()
        .simple(messageRouteConfig.getFrom() + "&fileName=${body}")
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, log, "message content (file content): ${body}")
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, log, "Starting processing file : ${file:name}")

It then processes and send it somewhere (this part works). I pass the name of the file (testing.csv) in the body and messageRouteConfig.getFrom() returns the following URI :
azure-storage-datalake:account01/test?clientId=clientId&tenantId=tenantId&clientSecret=secret&directoryName=/foo/bar

The issue is that the directoryName option doesn't seem to be taken into account. In the data lake, the file location is : test/foo/bar/testing.csv.
But when trying to get it, Camel seems to try to reach : test/testing.csv.
I also tried it this way (removing directoryName from the URI) without any success either :
from("direct:updateThings")
            .setHeader("CamelAzureStorageDataLakeDirectoryName", constant("/foo/bar"))
            .pollEnrich()
            .simple(messageRouteConfig.getFrom() + "&fileName=${body}")
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, log, "message content (file content): ${body}")
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, log, "Starting processing file : ${file:name}")

But if I remove any directoryName options and pass /foo/bar/testing.csv in the body (as the filename), it works. Any idea as to what to do here ?
Side question : anyway to get the read file name ? I tried logging it (as per the last line), but it doesn't seem to work.
Thanks a lot !

Are you using normal v2 storage or azure data lake gen2 storage accounts (hierarchical namespace) enabled?

I hope this helps to resolve your query.


I'm trying to setup a camel route in java, reading a csv in an Azure Data Lake and processing it.

I followed this Official Camel documentation,
You can use the below code to read csv file from azure-data lake using camel route.
Code:

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        DataLakeComponent azureStorageDataLakeComponent = new DataLakeComponent();
        DataLakeConfiguration configuration = new DataLakeConfiguration();
      
        configuration.setClientId("xxxx");
        configuration.setTenantId("xxxx");
        configuration.setClientSecret("Bxxxx");
        azureStorageDataLakeComponent.setConfiguration(configuration);
        context.addComponent("azure-storage-datalake", azureStorageDataLakeComponent);
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("direct:start")
                    .to("azure-storage-datalake:venkat8912/test?operation=getFile&fileName=foo/bar/001.csv")
                    .process(new Processor() {
                        @Override
                        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                            // Retrieve file content as InputStream
                            InputStream inputStream = exchange.getMessage().getBody(InputStream.class);
                            String fileContent = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                            fileContent = fileContent.replaceAll("(?m)^[ \t]*\r?\n", ""); // Remove empty lines
                            System.out.println("File Content:\n" + fileContent);
                        }
                    })
                    .to("mock:results");
            }
        });

        // Start the context
        context.start();

        // Send a message to trigger the route
        context.createProducerTemplate().sendBody("direct:start", null);

        // Allow the route to run for a while before stopping the context
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        
        // Stop the context
        context.stop();
    }
}

Output:
File Content:
PassengerId,Survived,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked
1,0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,1,0,A/5 21171,7.25,,S
2,1,1,"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)",female,38,1,0,PC 17599,71.2833,C85,C
3,1,3,"Heikkinen, Miss. Laina",female,26,0,0,STON/O2. 3101282,7.925,,S
4,1,1,"Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)",female,35,1,0,113803,53.1,C123,S
5,0,3,"Allen, Mr. William Henry",male,35,0,0,373450,8.05,,S
6,0,3,"Moran, Mr. James",male,,0,0,330877,8.4583,,Q
7,0,1,"McCarthy, Mr. Timothy J",male,54,0,0,17463,51.8625,E46,S
8,0,3,"Palsson, Master. Gosta Leonard",male,2,3,1,349909,21.075,,S
9,1,3,"Johnson, Mrs. Oscar W (Elisabeth Vilhelmina Berg)",female,27,0,2,347742,11.1333,,S
10,1,2,"Nasser, Mrs. Nicholas (Adele Achem)",female,14,1,0,237736,30.0708,,C



Yeah, I can see that working, but you're puting the file path in the file name, which is already working for me, I was trying to use the directoryName URI parameter, but I think I'll just concat the path to the fileName and use that. Although your way of doing it seems a bit cleaner than my long string with parameters, thanks !

Quick question though : does using .to with operation=getFile do the same thing as .pollEnrich().simple(<URI>) ?

I never tried like that but i followed the official docs to read csv file.

operation=getFile accepts filename so i passed directory in the filename itself.

@Paehrin Is the below approach worked for you?

I did use this way (putting the path in fileName to do it yes, since it was the only one that did. Thanks !
